# Trigger not firing for all rows when inserting multiple rows SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Am facing a problem with trigger.

I created a trigger for a table like this

```
 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[manageAttributes] 
ON [dbo].[tr_levels]
AFTER insert
AS 
BEGIN

set nocount on
declare @levelid int

select @levelid=levelid  from inserted
insert into testtable(testid) values(@levelid)
-- Insert statements for trigger here

END
```

But when I insert rows into table tr_levels like this

```
insert int tr_levels (column1,colum2) values(1,2)
```

trigger triggered perfectly

But when I tried to insert into table as a bulk like this

```
insert int tr_levels (column1,colum2) values(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)..
```

Trigger doesnt fires for all the rows. It fires only one time for the first row. Is that bug with SQL or is there a solution to trigger the trigger for all rows insertion in a bulk insert query

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Requesting a little support. I didnt understand that point. I mean how to tweak the trigger so that it should work for every rows

Comment: You've been talking in the comments as if you have a need to perform an action for each row inserted. Is there something you need to do that you can't do all at once with all the records in `inserted`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does fire for *all* rows - *once* - but you're ignoring the other rows by acting as if `inserted` only contains one. `select @scalar_variable=column from inserted` will arbitrarily retrieve a value from one of the rows and ignore the others. Write a set-based insert using `inserted` in a `FROM` clause

You need to treat `inserted` as a table that can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. So, something like:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[manageAttributes] 
ON [dbo].[tr_levels]
AFTER insert
AS 
BEGIN

set nocount on
insert into testtable(testid)
select levelid from inserted

END
```

Comment: Thats it boss..  thanks for that.. But just a clarification.. because of this issue we cant update another table upon each insertion, isnt it (Without using cursor). Insert is fine as considering special table INSERTED as a whole. but update will make some troubles I think..

Comment: @sforsandeep - you should always try to write all of your code to think about sets of rows, not one row at a time. Oftentimes, you can do a set-based `UPDATE` just fine (SQL Server allows `UPDATE ... FROM` which has some issues but can usually work okay)

Answer (score 1):

You have the same issue many people have that: you think the trigger is fired per row. It is not - it is per operation. And `inserted` is a table. You take one (random) value and ignore the rest. Fix that and it will work.

Triggers fire once per statement in the base table. So if you insert 5 rows in one statement, the trigger fires once and `inserted` has the 5 rows.

Comment: So I guess trigger is not Perfect at all since according to theory it should trigger after every insert (Doesnt mean bulk or single). So needs to go for splitting the bulk insert query to different insert statements.

Comment: @sforsandeep According to WHICH theory? THe one you make up? Guess what - the behavior s as documented, is in line with the SQL set approach and is generally accepted by anyone reading the documentation. There is no theory you state.

Comment: Sorry Friend, I only mean what I understand.. Please ignore it  as I mentioned theory..